# How to setValue() when it's an entire row in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setvalue

I've been trying to run this one and althought currentRow has about 23 columns, I only have the first column's value set:

```
targetSheet.setActiveRange(targetSheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 1))
 .setValue(currentRow);
```

I've tried seValues() instead, but it doesn't work.

Here's currentRow logged:
[image]

Any light?

Comment: **1**. What is `currentRow` ? `console.log(currentRow)` to tell us what it contains **2**. you don't need `setActiveRange`, you can set the values without activating any range **3**.  I guess you tried `setValues()` instead of `seValues()`;

Comment: Check my updated answer if it works for you. Assuming `maxIndex` is a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

You have 1D array, make it 2D:

```
targetSheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2,1,1,currentRow.length).setValues([currentRow])
```

---

- You don't need active ranges, you can directly paste the data
- If you want to paste multiple values in the sheet with `setValues`, the input `currentRow` needs to be an 2D array (the result of `getValues`).

The following example copies the values from `A1:W1` and pastes them to `A2:W2`:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('target'); // put the name of your sheet
  const currentRow = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,1,23).getValues(); // range A1:W1
  targetSheet.getRange(2,1,1,23).setValues(currentRow); // set values to A2:W2
}
```